# How can I dynamically create a StringGrid at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm having trouble creating a StringGrid at runtime. Baring in mind I'm not that experienced at stuff like this, can anyone explain how to do this? This is the code I have so far...

```
unit uDynStringGrid;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, grids;

type
  TfrmMyForm = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MyGrid : TStringGrid ;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMyForm: TfrmMyForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyStringGrid : TStringGrid ;
begin
  MyStringGrid := TStringGrid.Create(frmMyForm);
  MyStringGrid.Visible := true ;
  MyStringGrid.left := 20 ;
  MyStringGrid.top := 20 ;
  MyStringGrid.rowcount := 5 ;
  MyStringGrid.colcount := 5 ;
  MyStringGrid.width := 100 ;
  MyStringGrid.height := 100 ;
  MyStringGrid.Enabled := true ;
  MyStringGrid.cells[1,1] := 'hi' ;
  MyGrid := TStringGrid.Create(frmMyForm) ;
  MyGrid := MyStringGrid ;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is missing is setting your grid parent `MyGrid.Parent := Self;`

Also, you don't need local variable `MyStringGrid`, since you have `MyGrid` variable declared at form level.

Another thing you should avoid is referencing form, in its own code, through global variable. Use `Self` instead.

```
procedure TfrmMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyGrid := TStringGrid.Create(Self);
  MyGrid.Parent := Self;
  MyGrid.Visible := true;
  MyGrid.left := 20;
  MyGrid.top := 20;
  MyGrid.rowcount := 5;
  MyGrid.colcount := 5;
  MyGrid.width := 100;
  MyGrid.height := 100;
  MyGrid.Enabled := true;
  MyGrid.cells[1, 1] := 'hi';
end;
```